# Unable to install package RCurl

Tags: r, ubuntu-14.04, package, rcurl, install.packages

I am having some problem with the `weatherData` package in R. As I am using this code:

```
a <- read.csv(url("http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/sfo/2016/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=27&monthend=5&yearend=2016&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA&format=1"), 
                  method ="libcurl")
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  unused argument (method = "libcurl")
```

After I searched a bit, I came to know maybe its due to `RCurl` package not being installed in my R version of 3.2.1. But as I started installing `RCurl`, I got this:

```
Cannot find curl-config
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RCurl’
* removing ‘/home/dell/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RCurl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that.  Just use `read.csv()` with the url, removing the call to `url()` as well. So try `read.csv("http://...")`.

Comment: Still getting the same error! @RichardScriven

Comment: It works fine for me on R 3.3.0 and using `read.csv("https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/sfo/2016/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=27&monthend=5&yearend=2016&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA&format=1")`

Comment: Oh...my R version is 3.2.2. Do you think this might be the issue?

Comment: Oh and can you tell me about the RCurl package. It ain't getting installed. @RichardScriven

Comment: Install RCurl by running `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcurl`

Comment: Using this I get this error: E: encountered a section with no package: header E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/list/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened. @xxfelixxx

Comment: Look here for MergeList issue: http://askubuntu.com/questions/30072/how-do-i-fix-a-problem-with-mergelist-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-err

Comment: Are you sure that `libcurl` is installed? Maybe try `sudo apt-get install libcurl3` in a linux terminal...

Comment: Yeah, libcurl3 is already installed. @RHertel

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach using plain old `curl` since the url content is not `csv` but actually `html`, then cleaning up the html, then loading it in R:

```
$ curl 'https://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/sfo/2016/1/1/CustomHistory.html?dayend=27&monthend=5&yearend=2016&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA&format=1' \ 
        > data.html
```

The content has trailing `<br >` markup

```
$ head -n 3 data.html 

PDT,Max TemperatureC,Mean TemperatureC,Min TemperatureC,DewPointC,MeanDew PointC,Min DewpointC,Max Humidity, Mean Humidity, Min Humidity, Max Sea Level PressurehPa, Mean Sea Level PressurehPa, Min Sea Level PressurehPa, Max VisibilityKm, Mean VisibilityKm, Min VisibilitykM, Max Wind SpeedKm/h, Mean Wind SpeedKm/h, Max Gust SpeedKm/h,Precipitationmm, CloudCover, Events,WindDirDegrees<br />

2016-1-1,9,6,3,0,-3,-6,76,57,38,1023,1021,1020,16,16,16,27,14,32,0.00,3,,90<br />
```

Lets eliminate this markup and turn this into csv.

```
$ cat data.html | perl -lpe 's|<br.*$||;' > data.csv
```

Now load it as usual in R

```
$ R

d <- read.csv('data.csv')

colnames(d)

 [1] "PDT"                        "Max.TemperatureC"          
 [3] "Mean.TemperatureC"          "Min.TemperatureC"          
 [5] "Dew.PointC"                 "MeanDew.PointC"            
 [7] "Min.DewpointC"              "Max.Humidity"              
 [9] "Mean.Humidity"              "Min.Humidity"              
 [11] "Max.Sea.Level.PressurehPa"  "Mean.Sea.Level.PressurehPa"
 [13] "Min.Sea.Level.PressurehPa"  "Max.VisibilityKm"          
 [15] "Mean.VisibilityKm"          "Min.VisibilitykM"          
 [17] "Max.Wind.SpeedKm.h"         "Mean.Wind.SpeedKm.h"       
 [19] "Max.Gust.SpeedKm.h"         "Precipitationmm"           
 [21] "CloudCover"                 "Events"                    
 [23] "WindDirDegrees"
```